# Only one of two Intel Wireless 7260 PCI Cards are assigned a logical name

Tags: 16.04, intel-wireless, pci

I have two wireless cards on a test PC I'm working on. And while I can see both cards, only the top card is actually getting assigned the logical (interface) name.

This seems to be interment (though I've only had this computer running for two days) because there has been at least one occasion that I have seen both cards assigned an interface name at the same time (via ifconfig and NM). However, when I've had to restart the computer, the names are not always assigned for the 2nd (bottom) card.

I've switched out the cards (with other cards), move the cards to other locations, exchanged the locations of the cards, BUT only the top most device is actually assigned the name.

I'm running:
4.4.0-36-generic GNU/Linux Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

The two cards are the same Intel Corporation Wireless 7260:

```
#cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:07\:00.0/modalias 
pci:v00008086d000008B1sv00008086sd00004070bc02sc80i00
#cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:06\:00.0/modalias 
pci:v00008086d000008B1sv00008086sd00004070bc02sc80i00
```

Only one of the devices is getting assigned a logical name:

```
#sudo lshw -class network
  ....
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 73
       serial: 7c:5c:f8:c4:a0:e5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-36-generic firmware=16.242414.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:50 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 73
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

dmesg does not show that the 2nd device on bus 0000:07:00.0 has been detected by the wifi driver (not sure what that first error is about)

```
 #dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    1.837914] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.850969] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    1.888274] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    1.888330] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    1.888548] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.103364] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
[    2.611257] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.611480] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.801484] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.801710] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
```

and ifconfig only shows one device (obviously since lshw showed that only one was getting assigned a logical name)

```
#ifconfig 
...

wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:5c:f8:c4:a0:e5  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found after finding and reading the note towards the bottom of this page: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release
And then finding the correct release

Previously, I had only been reading this page: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi
This actually does explain that -17.ucode is the latest and greatest firmware for the 7260 cards. However it does not actually point to a download link...

The core_release page does. And after installing it (-17.ucode) and re-running the same reboot permutations (switch cards, move cards, etc...) I have found that -17.ucode works flawlessly.